# C# XNA - Can't Deserialize Element

Tags: c#, xna, xml, serialization

So This is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<XnaContent xmlns:ns="Microsoft.Xna.Framework">
  <!-- TODO: replace this Asset with your own XML asset data. -->
  <Asset Type="ScreenLoader.DataLoader">
    <Path>Graphics/Backgrounds/background_0</Path>
  </Asset>
</XnaContent>
```

And my XmlManager class:

```
public class XmlManager<T>
{
    public Type Type { get; private set; }
    public T Load(string path)
    {
        T instance;
        using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader(path))
        {
            XmlSerializer xml = new XmlSerializer(Type);
            instance = (T)xml.Deserialize(reader);
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

And my DataLoader class:

```
namespace ScreenLoader
{
    public class DataLoader
    {
        public static string Path;
    }
}
```

The compiler error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line
>   Error       There was an error while deserializing intermediate XML. 'Element' is an invalid XmlNodeType. Line 5, position 6.

So that's what I did: Added XNA Game Library `ScreenLoader` to my project. Added the DataLoader class in it. Then I added reference to it in both my Content project and my Game project. Then I changed the game project to depend on the library. Then I adjusted the build order of the game project so that the library is built first. And I STILL CANNOT comprehend why the compiler complains like this. I just want to load content from XML files and have them compiled to XNB when I ship the game but I really need to know what I am missing. Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/660811/element-is-an-invalid-xmlnodetype

Comment: @Byte56 that link is to a different issue. This question deals with how to use the automatic deserialization in Xna. I believe I understand the OP's specific Q and can give the OP usefull information. Can you open if and let me try?

Comment: @SteveH Sure thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to write code to deserialize your xml file. The Xml deserialization in Xna is automatic so you do not need your XmlManager class at all.

Add your Xml file (myXmlFile.xml) to your content project just like you would a texture or model. This will allow the build process to convert it from xml to serialized xnb. Now your project is aware of myXmlFile.xnb and when you load it using the Content Manager, it will automatically deserialize it for you. It was one of the really cool things about Xna so stick with it.

```
//In your Game1 class scope variables:

ScreenLoader.DataLoader myDataLoader;

//then in your LoadContent Method:

myDataLoader = Content.Load<ScreenLoader.DataLoader>("myXmlFile");// it knows what a DataLoader is because you built that project first. the ("myXmlFile") refers to the myXmlFile.xnb, not the myXmlFile.xml.
```

Viola! myDataLoader.Path now holds "Graphics/Backgrounds/background_0"

here's a link:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2008/08/12/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-intermediateserializer.aspx

Comment: Yeah, but that doesn't fix the error I'm getting inside the XML file `'Element' is an invalid XmlNodeType.`

Comment: Your error pops up when your code runs your xmlManager class. The point is, you don't need that class. Delete it. That class can only act upon XML. You don't want to ship XML with your game so there is no point in writing code to parse XML. Let the content manager do it automatically to the xnb.

Comment: @SteveH What should be the build action for the XML file? I deleted the XmlManager before I wrote that comment and still have the same error. I used the code in your answer but I get that error. When I double click on it it leads me to the line with `<Path></Path>`. Obviously I can't remove that line or `Path` will be null.

Comment: Upon further investigation I found that the problem was that my string `Path` was static. Apparently XNA's internal XML Deserializer doesn't like static fields. Thanks for the quick answer and sorry for my simple mistake.

Comment: Glad you got it. Your Xml file can be used for lots of game initial game settings and configurations.